# RSpec cannot find route for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm dealing with a seemingly strange issue while trying to run unit tests on a nested `resources` controller. Here's my setup:

`routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: 'api' do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users do
        resources 'item-configurations',
          controller: :item_configuration,
            as: :item_configurations,
            on: :member
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/api/v1/item_configurations_controller.rb`:

```
module Api::V1                              
  class ItemConfigurationsController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @user = authorize User.find(params[:user_id])      
      @item_configuration = authorize @user.item_configurations.find(params[:id])

      success @item_configuration
    end
  end
end
```

and finally, `spec/controllers/api/v1/item_configurations_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::V1::ItemConfigurationsController do
  describe '#show' do
    it 'renders an item configuration' do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      configuration = FactoryGirl.create(:item_configuration)

      get :show, params: {user_id: user.id, id: configuration.id}
      expect(response.status).to equal(200)
    end
  end
end
```

When I make a request to `/users/1/item-configurations/4` I'm able to get a response, just as I'd expect. The issue comes from when I run `rspec`, I get the following error:

```
  1) Api::V1::ItemConfigurationsController#show renders an item configuration
     Failure/Error: get :show, params: {user_id: user.id, id: configuration.id}

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/item_configurations", :id=>1, :user_id=>1}
```

Normally these errors arise when a parameter is missing from the request, but in this case everything appears to be there (both `user_id` and `id`). I've also tried this on other routes on the controller (`#index` also works when sent a `GET` but does not work in rspec), adding a `format: :json` param, etc. but nothing seems to solve it.

Am I crazy or is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: To me it looks similar to [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1586) issue. Don't know if it helps or not. I'd also try renaming `Rails.application.routes.draw` to `Yourappname::Application.routes.draw`

Comment: Am I missing something or is rspec infering `TrayConfigurationsController` in the failure output but you're describing `ItemConfigurationsController `.  Anything weird in `log/test.log` ?

Comment: whoops, that's a mistake. I renamed some of the models for the purpose of this question in order to make it more generic. I've fixed that in the latest edit.

Comment: also nothing in `log/test.log`, just some lines about the queries run before attempting that GET request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apart from the typo `controller: :item_configuration` (singular, while controller is plural) in your routes you specify `on` parameter on `resources`. It seems to be it acts like a constraint on `resources`, rather than as a "type" of interaction.

From console:

```
app.url_for({:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/item_configurations", :id=>"2", :user_id=>"1"})
=> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/item_configurations", :id=>"2", :user_id=>"1"}
app.url_for({:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/item_configurations", :id=>"2", :user_id=>"1", on: :member})
=> "http://www.example.com/v1/users/1/item_configurations/2"
```

Therefore, use `member` block in routes to achieve desired behaviour:

```
...
resources :users do
  member do
     resources :configuration_items 
  end
end
...
```

Comment: YES, that was it! Thank you so much, you've saved me more time/sanity than you know, haha.